Is timerfd thread safe?
Surprisingly, documentation for timerfd_create, timerfd_settime, timerfd_gettime never mentions word "thread" and example code is also single threaded.
Should I assume that it is not safe?
I was hoping to use timer with epoll on one thread and call timerfd_settime from other threads. But if authors of timerfd were not aware of existence of threads, then it may not be safe, right?

System calls in Linux are atomic. You can share timer fd not only between threads but between processes as well. epoll_wait() only signalizes when descriptor would not block on subsequent read() or write().

@dimich Yes, this was my understanding too, but can I rely on it if it is not documented anywhere? For comparison, eventfd manual clearly states "Thread safety" : "MT-Safe", but if timerfd creators were not aware of existence of threads, they could have made any kind of mistakes,

eventfd is supposed to be triggered from another thread/process. timerfd event is triggered from kernel.

@dimich But there are still many possible races here: multiple simultaneous calls to timerfd_settime or a call to timerfd_settime while the timer is being processed by a kernel thread. If not done properly, it will cause corruption. I guess they should use some mutex in the kernel.

timerfd_settime() is a syscall, it should be atomic. Processing in kernel context must be atomic as well, it will lead to race even in single-threaded process otherwise. You can explore kernel timers code in linux/kernel/time/

@dimich timerfd is actually here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/timerfd.c And it not automatically atomic, simply by virtue of being syscall. They have to use spinlock a lot and have comments like "We need to stop the existing timer before reprogramming it to the new values." . So, simply being syscal is not enough, it is pretty complex code to make thread safe kernel API.

In my experience of implementing timer FDs and monitoring them with epoll_wait(), I am generally satisfied that the design approach is thread-safe, and have (so far) only encountered one issue that could be attributed to multi-threading.
If one thread cancels a timer between the point where it expired, but before a separate thread handles the EPOLLIN caused by the expiry, then that polling thread can be blocked by the call which is trying to read() the timer FD to clear it.
The solution in that case is to make the timer FD a non-blocking descriptor when you call timerfd_create(), i.e. using TFD_NONBLOCK in the flags parameter.
Then, when the EPOLLIN is handled and you read() the timerfd, you will get a detectable failure from which you can reasonably infer "timer was reset/modified after it expired".
